# PHP - get the value of href/id

Tags: php

hello I have a calendar... and I want to put clickable on every days like... 1 2 3 4 5 6...
and for example...
current date is October 2013... then when I click the number 8.. then I would create like this...

```
$clickedDay = 8;
$month = "October";
$year = 2013;
```

i just need to get the clickedDay... but don't know how to that please help me...

```
for($i=1; $i<= $day_count; $i++) {
    echo '<a href="" class="cal_day" id="' . $i . '">';
    echo '<div class="day_heading">' . $i . '</div>';
    echo '</a>';
}
```

this is my code... still don't know cause DIV can't be a clickable so i use `<a href>` i think

Comment: you can get by GET method like `href="some.php?id=$i"` then `$_GET['id']`

Comment: A `div` can be made to look and behave like it's clickable. What do you want to do when someone clicks it?

Comment: @Frits yeah... how to do that?

Comment: @JeraldPunx: with the use of jQuery you can make a div clickable

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly straight forward to make a `div` clickable:

```
HTML
<div class="clickable" id="click_me_div">Click me!</div>

JS
document.getElementById("click_me_div").addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert("you clicked me!");
});

CSS
.clickable:hover { text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer; }
```